# Good guidelines for developing an ecommerce application

Tags: android, e-commerce

I'm making an ecommerce application on Android and, as it is my first serious project, I'm trying to figure out beforehand the best approach to do this.

The application talks to a web service (magento api, meaning soap or xml rpc unfortunately) and gets all the content on the phone (product categories, product details, user credentials etc.). I think it should do lazy loading or something like that.

So, I was thinking to keep the user credentials in a custom Object which will be kept in a `SharedPreferences` so that every Activity can easily access it. I'll use a couple of `ListView`s to show the content and `AsyncTask` to fetch the data needed. Should I keep all the data in memory in objects or should I use some sort of cache or a local database? Also, I'm planning to use a `HashMap` with `SoftReferences` to hold the bitmaps I am downloading. But wouldn't this eat a lot of memory?

How can all the activities have access to all these objects (ecommerce basket etc.)? I'm thinking of passing them using Intents but this doesn't seem right to me. Can SharedPreferences be used for a lot of objects and are there any concurrency issues?

Any pointers would be really appreciated. What are some good guidelines? What classes should I look into? Do you know of any resources on the Internet for me to check out?

Comment: i'm about to develop eCommerce android app so if you could give some guidance it would be of great help @kaciula

Comment: @kaciula I've just started to build an eCommerce app but stucked. I think at the same stage where you were 5 years ago :). If you can answer this question yourself it will be very helpful to others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A very detailed question I will do my best to answer it. 
I used the following approach in my application:

- I save the user credentials in the shared preferences. The preferences can only hold custom objects if they are serializable and writing and reading from flash memory takes a lot of time. Therefore I load the preferences on startup and store them in memory.
- I try to keep all the data in memory that is needed in many places and in a consistent state, all the other memory is passed via serializing to json and passing through an intent or i pass only ids and I re fetch it from the net. (There is definitively a possibility for cashing in a local database but the effort to keep it up to date is to much work at the moment.) To store objects that take to long to reload from internal memory or network and re parse it I use a custom [application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) that holds the reference to some controller objects which manage the caching. The application will stay in memory until your app is closed. This is convenient but can result in needing way to much memory if you are not careful.
- The bitmaps that are downloaded by my program are cached on two layers. At the first time I want to access an image I create a image manager object inside my activity scope. That object will try to find the bitmap in an internal map. If it is not there it will try to load it from phone memory if it is not in the phone memory it will download it from the net, store it in the cache folder of my app and put it in the map. In this way the bitmap is accessible as long as the activity runs and is cleaned up at the moment the user changes to another screen. Until now this is sufficient for me.

At the end just begin programming and come back if you encounter other questions or errors and post some more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Many useful techniques that you will need to use: ContentProviders, AsyncTasks, Bitmap Caching, ... are used in Romain Guys 'Shelvs' (http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/01/19/shelves-an-open-source-android-application/) app. It's a great start point to get the into a recommend Android flow.

Comment: Shelves is a bit too complicated for me at the moment. I've started taking it slow, step-by-step.