# eCommerce native android app

Tags: android

I'm about to develop eCommerce native android app similar to ebay and flipkart but at this point have many doubts they are.

- should all the data required to show in app must be fetched using
  services at the background and stored in temporary memory before app
  is opened or must the request to fetch data must be sent at the click
  of button option. because on click of button consumes more time for
  fetching images and in case of eCommerce app there will be more
  images.
- In eCommerce app, using sqlite to store and retrieving data is better
  or using preferences or any other better alternative?
- Which is the best method to develop eCommerce app i.e hard coding
  everything or usi
  ng RSS feed option from website or is there any other alternative?
- next doubt is regarding size of apk. how to optimally reduce the size
  of apk while developing such big app ( well i do know about pro-guard
  and lint and remove repeated codes and other stuff but still it
  doesn't reduce to that extreme level). i have developed an app
  similar to facebook but the size of apk is 16MB which is really very
  huge. as per my prediction this eCommerce app might take 20MB but
  when checked with flipkart(6.3MB), OLX(4.96MB), Jabong(5.1MB) how is
  this possible... the basic helloworld app takes nearly 1MB...
- How to optimally reduce the number of server client request to reduce
  the hit count in server.

Any advice and help from experienced people will be of great help.
sorry for long post and thanks

Comment: This will help you [Good guidelines for developing an ecommerce application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006643/good-guidelines-for-developing-an-ecommerce-application

Comment: 1. when you want to show data, then only call webservice. 2.if you have so many datas, then use sqlite. else use shared preferences. 3.hard coding. 4.no its wrong. if there are so many images/files in res folder, then only your apk size will bigger. else, it will be small. 5.whenever you want, then you have to hit the server for getting data. if the data's are static, then store it on sqlite and reuse it